# Error in C# code while using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am using code from other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf) and i am getting the error as

> Error 1   The non-generic type
>   'iTextSharp.text.List' cannot be used
>   with type arguments
>
> Error 2   The name 'HTMLWorker' does not
>   exist in the current context
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name
>   'HTMLWorker' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

My code so far is as follows:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Extract data from Page (pd).
    Label16.Text = Editor1.Content; // Attribute    

    // makae ready HttpContext
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    // Create PDF document
    Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
    //PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDocument.Open();
    //WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string htmlText = Editor1.Content;

    List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null);
    for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
    {
        pdfDocument.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
    }

    //pdfDocument.Add(new Paragraph(IElement));
    pdfDocument.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

}

Please Help me to resolve the error. What i am trying is to get the contents (non html) from htmleditor and display in a pdf file. please confirm me whether what i am trying to do is correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Prefix your List like

```
System.Collections.Generics.List<IElement> htmlarraylist
```

2.Looks like you didn't import the namespace of `HTMLWorker`

**EDIT**:I googled for you ,the namespace could be any of these three.I doubt it could be the last one,but i am not sure.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
```

Comment: What is the import for HTMLWorker?

Answer (score 3):

There's a name conflict in this code - you are `using iTextSharp.text` namespace and trying to use standard `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class.

Either you need to remove `using iTextSharp.text` and use its classes with explicit namespace or use explicit namespace for `List<T>`.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null);
```

The third solution is to use [aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

And for the second error, you need to import `HTMLWorker` namespace. Put

```
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
```

at the top.