# Create simple PDF document on the fly with C#, which library to use?

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I want to convert a simple HTML table into PDF in the memory (not file system) like this:

```
string pdfContent = "<table>...</table>";
byte[] pdf = WantedComponent.CreatePDF(pdfContent);
```

My HTML table has simple text without any formatting.

Comment: There are LOTS of "covert html to pdf" questions floating around SO.  Check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try iTextSharp.  It can render simple HTML as a PDF.  I've tried using it but ran into some issues with tables with colspans, but if your HTML table is very simple it might work for you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Also, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf) for some sample code on how to convert HTML to PDF.

Comment: iTextSharp is NOT free. It's open-sourced under AGPL license.

Comment: @Bobrovsky Good point, sorry about that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Err... *GPL is the very definition of Free.  It's not free-as-in-beer-for-closed-source-use, no.

Comment: @Mark Storer I think that BSD is the very definition of Free. Other people may think other way. So let's not start another holy war.

Comment: Agreed.  The various GPLs impose "viral" restrictions, BSD does not.  Overloading can work great for functions, but can really fall down in something as imprecise as English:  Free