# How convert word document to pdf programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ms-word

I try to generate word document using this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/doc";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
filename=" + DateTime.Now + ".doc");

var strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();

strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<h1 title='Heading' align='Center'style='font-family: verdana; font 
-size: 80 % ;color: black'><u>Document Heading</u> </h1> ");

strHTMLContent.Append("<br>");
strHTMLContent.Append("<table align='Center'>");

// Row with Column headers
strHTMLContent.Append("<tr>");
strHTMLContent.Append("<td style='width:100px; background:# 99CC00'>
<b>Column1 </b>  </td>");

strHTMLContent.Append("<td style='width:100px;background:# 99CC00'>
<b>Column2 </b>  </td>");

strHTMLContent.Append("<td style='width:100px; background:# 99CC00'>
<b>Column 3</b></td>");
strHTMLContent.Append(" </tr> ");

// First Row Data
strHTMLContent.Append("<tr>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<td style='width:100px'></td>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<td style='width:100px'>b</td>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<td style='width:100px'>c</td>");
strHTMLContent.Append("</tr>");

// Second Row Data
strHTMLContent.Append("<tr>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<td style='width:100px'>d</td>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<td style='width:100px'>e</td>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<td style='width:100px'>f</td>");
strHTMLContent.Append("</tr>");

strHTMLContent.Append("</table>");

strHTMLContent.Append("<br><br>");
strHTMLContent.Append(
    "<p align='Center'> Note : This is a dynamically 
            generated word document  </p> ");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
//  HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(strHTMLContent);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Does anyone know how to convert this word document to a PDF file programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building HTML to convert, you can use [iTextSharp](http://nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp) API to go from HTML to PDF: [ITextSharp HTML to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf). iTextSharp is free.

Answer (score 0):

MS .Net Framework does not provide anything by default you will have to use thrid party API for it

For e.g see the link the API easyPDF does conversion using C#   http://www.pdfonline.com/easypdf/sdk/programming-pdf/csharp/index.htm?_kk=%2Bpdf%20%2Bc%23&_kt=0e3c1bed-3404-4289-8143-77333a737850&gclid=CPT--pXTk7ECFa4mtAodKn5ylw

Comment: @Alex Yes it is not and I doubt their is any free API that will give the functionality

Answer (score 0):

After using many different options, this was by far the best one we found.  Expensive, but amazing speed and versatility, with decent (though not excellent) support docs.  http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Support.aspx#csharp - well worth a look if it's for a commercial project where the cost can be passed on.