# How to Convert a WordProcessingDocument to a pdf

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, openxml, wordprocessingml

I am facing a situation where I am filling an MS Word Template online using OpenXML with values extracted from a database. I would then like the final user in the business process to get an email with the mentioned template fully filled as a PDF. I have tried Microsoft.Office.Interop but the service does not work as expected.

I would like to know if there is an ASP.NET C# component out there that does the above conversion reliably and simply, paid or unpaid.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447229/how-convert-word-document-to-pdf-programmatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to go with ASPOSE.WORDS They really have a great component that has the exact functionality I was looking for.