# Html string text and formats in dataset, report

Tags: c#

I have a html string..

```
<div id="P1">
    <table id="P1Table">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                ABCD: <span style="font-weight:bold;>First</span>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
                ABCD: <span style="font-weight:bold;>First</span>
            </td>
    </table>
    <table id="Table Two">
        <tr>
            <td class="one">
                First:
            </td>
            <td class="two">
                None
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">
                First:
            </td>
            <td class="two">
                None
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">
                First:
            </td>
            <td class="two">
                None
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the text visualizer for a string. This is being displayed on the webpage using a asp literal.

Now here is what I need some help on. I am trying to get the text and formatting (html visualizer) in a pdf report. So any idea on how to do this. 
If it would be easier to get this info to a dataset and then use reprtviewer to generate the report, how would I get the html text and format to a dataset.

Thanks

Comment: you can conrver the page aspx to pdf with it url

Comment: FYI, your HTML is invalid. On line 7: `<<td width="50%">`. You also have an unclosed <tr> on the 3rd line from the end.

Comment: @Joce also `<span style="font-weight:bold;>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to convert html to pdf. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835265/663036) answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin/blob/master/README.md) is a .NET wrapper over the fairly well-regarded standalone [HtmlToPdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). This can be used to do what you require.