# Javascript: PDF export button for webpage

Tags: javascript

I would like any pointers or resources to where I can get a java-script that allows my export button on my site to export my current page to pdf.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: i use this to create a PDF from some html template: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no javascript library which would allow to create a pdf file. 
Mozilla implemented complete PDF reader in js and includes it in latest Firefox, but that is huge library. **EDIT**: there is jspdf which seems to be able to do that.

I think you should go with server side PDF engine.

DOMPdf is a PHP library which allows to render complete HTML with CSS, images etc to PDF document. It even has a example php script which put on server allows to convert submited html to PDF.

Your javascript "button" should just get the document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML and post that HTML to the DOMPdf script. You should get more or less correct PDF out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Link of Zend_Pdf : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html

You can also try jspdf :  http://jspdf.com/

Answer (score 1):

i unable to get your requirement, i hope you require to take pdf of web page.

if my understanding is correct, Please refer below link

http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx

also see the existing post [ITextSharp HTML to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) for this purpose. I am using it to generate pdf of html pages.

But it is not possible alone with javascript. You have to have some server side code for the same.