# how to convert HTML which is stored in strResponse to PDF file and i am using itextSharp dll

Tags: c#

I need to create pdf of webpage using its url.
I got the HTML of web page using

```
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
        string strResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Can any one help in how to convert HTML which is stored in strResponse to PDF file and i am using itextSharp dll.

Thanks
Ratika

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTMLWorker of iTextsharp to convert Html to Pdf as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835265/1260405).

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'. Can you plz help with this. --ratika

Comment: Document document = new Document();

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"d:/PDFfile.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
            hw.Parse(new StringReader(strResponse));
            document.Close();

Comment: any answer for above Shriek

Comment: @user2439490 that code works for me, at least for google.com, are you perhaps trying to convert another page?

Comment: @user2439490 same as yours, didn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

There is no automation unfortunately. You will have to parse it and add the content to the pdf document on your own. You could try using a plugin called [XMLWorker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/) to aide in the conversion but it's going to be a brute force process.