# Report Designer for ItextSharp

Tags: devexpress, report, itext, designer

Is there a front end report designer, like devexpress, that can generate itextsharp source code?  I'm looking to replace devexpress reports we currently have and use something else.  But I really don't want to write code for the look and feel of the report.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no such designer exists. About the closest that I can think of would be to use a designer to create HTML and just have iTextSharp parse that.

Comment: Thanks, that may be a better idea instead of a designer anyway. This may help others [html to pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2835265/1274934)